# Whats the probability of a random 6digit number recurring

Tags: probability

Im creating a function that creates a random 6 digit number.
I want to use it as a unique key in a table.
So my question is what the probability of one of the numbers recurring if i call the function max 14 times.
I was thinking that i could have an if and every time check but if the probability is low enough i would be able to save that processing power/time.

Comment: What's wrong with generating a random $6$ digit number $n$, then statically storing the numbers $n$, $n+1$, ..., $n+13$ (modulo $1\,000\,000$), so you can guarantee you have fourteen distinct integers, that you return sequentially from subsequent calls to your function?

Comment: @EricTowers likely the OP would want them all to have the same distribution, your solution makes them dependent...

Comment: Basically for this job you are expected to create an ordered list like `[100000..999999]`, then [`shuffle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45967133/4543207) it and pick the first needed many random **and** unique 6 digit numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a step in the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).  The first number cannot be a duplicate.  The second has $\frac {99\ 999}{100\ 000}$ chance of not being a duplicate.  Assuming the second is not a duplicate, the third has $\frac {99\ 998}{100\ 000}$ chance of not being a duplicate and so on.

The overall chance of no duplicate is
$$\frac{99\ 999!}{100\ 000^{13}\cdot 99\ 986!}\approx 0.999$$ so you have about $1$ chance in a thousand of a duplicate.  Essentially you have $\frac 12 \cdot 14 \cdot 13=91$ pairs, each of which will match with probability $\frac 1{100\ 000}$

Comment: commas make numbers unreadable; and one $9$ is redundant; [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=99999%21%2F%28100000%5E13*99986%21%29)